# How to determine the selected row

Tags: knockout.js

I have a table bound like this:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: reportItems">
  <tr>
      <td><a data-bind="text: OrderPostCloseStatusName" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editStatus"></a></td>

     </tr>
  </tbody>
```

This works and shows a Bootstrap Model when the link is clicked.  However, I need to know which item has been clicked on so that I can show the appropriate data in the model.  For example, I would like a property on the ViewModel called selectedItemId that would be bound somehow so the viewModel would know which item is selected when the user clicks the link.

How can I do that?

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new observable in your viewmodel:

```
self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
```

Add a [click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) to the link:

```
  <td><a data-bind="text: OrderPostCloseStatusName, click: $root.selectedItem" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editStatus"></a></td>
```

Now if you'd like an observable with the selected id, you could create an computed:

```
self.selectedItemId = ko.computed(function() {
    var selectedItem = ko.unwrap(self.selectedItem);
    if (selectedItem) {
        return ko.unwrap(selectedItem.id);
    }
});
```